# Classification of Imbalanced and Streaming Time Series Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, unbalanced-classes, online-algorithms

I have a question about **classification of time series**. Data has two features and I want to classify it into 5 classes. We have a **stream** of data and new data is generated every 5 seconds. Moreover in some classes we have **inadequate data for training** so we have classification problem with imbalanced data. I want to classify new data using machine learning methods according to the **pattern shown in the figures**. What methods do you suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your datastream looks more like a regression problem for me.
And in case you are trying to make a classification problem I suggest labelling the segments by hand, since it seems that you have a certain idea what the segments should represent.

Otherwise positive slope (green) and negative slope (pink) can be easily estimated and thus resemble a feature vector.